# Get a character in list<Node*> and return

Tags: c++, list

Now I have a definition

```
list<Node*> _nodes;
```

and a function

```
Node* Directory::getChild(int index) {

}
```

then how can I add a return in the `getChild()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
Node* Directory::getChild(int index) {
  assert(index >= 0 && index < _nodes.size());
  list<Node*>::iterator it = _nodes.begin();
  advance(it, index);
  return *it;
}
```

Note that, if you need random access, `std::list` is a poor choice for a container class.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have solute the problem.